# how to implement Rooting angularJS with customize url

Tags: angularjs, routes

I want to have on the URL of my application like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/#/?id=XYZ
```

I don't found how to configure this on angularjs app module
My implementation is like that:

```
angular.module('APP', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/?id="+":id", {
    templateUrl: "views/sign/sign.html",
    controller: "SignCtrl"
  });
  // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to specify

it will be like

```
angular.module('APP', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "views/sign/sign.html",
    controller: "SignCtrl"
  });
  // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

and in your SingCtrl.

when you write $routeParam than you will have objects of params which are passed as a query parameter.

so you will get $routePara.id if you pass like ?id=anything

Do not have to worry if you want to catch the query param like ?id=abs&name=test

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "url" attribute to your $routeProvider object.

Something like:

$routeProvider.when("/?id="+":id", {
    templateUrl: "views/sign/sign.html",
    url: 'the Url you want to use',
    controller: "SignCtrl"
  });

PS.: I suggest you to use ui-router instead of ngRoute. Check it out later.